# Magento 2 Equivalent for Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')

Tags: magento2.2, catalog, layer

For Magento1, On:-

app/design/frontend/Mypackage/Mytheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

**I'm using following code:-**

Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId()

Same code I want to use for Magento2, how can I achieve?

Note:- Don't want to use registry.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private $layerResolver;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

    $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
}

public function getCurrentCategoryId()
{
    return $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
}
```

or you can use

```
$objectmanager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category_id =  $objectmanager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! by including classes it works & I achive the expected output but objectmanager way doesn't work.